# Wrote some code for a model.PositiveIntegerField but changed it to Float and it wont register

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am currently working with Django and I just added a `models.PositiveIntegerField` and then migrated but decided I wanted to change it to `models.FloatField`. After making that change I went into django admin dashboard and was checking out an entry that I made which had 0 set as quantity at first but after I migrated the new changes it is now 0.0

Now the problem is that if I try to save a number, say 5.0, it would require me to enter a whole number. Even if I try to save the page with 0.0 it would summon an error. Should I reverse my migration?

Comment: what is the error you get?

Comment: it's better for us to help if you provide models and error code

Comment: it is more of a error pop up on the django admin that is reading `Enter a whole number`